# rollup preserveModules in yarn monorepo outputs full project path

Tags: vue.js, rollup, rollupjs

I'm working on a vue component library, but have issues creating an `esm` output for consumers tree-shaking my library. I'm using rollup to compile my files, with the `preserveModules` option. This is run inside a yarn monorepo.

The modules are emitted into `\office-fabric\packages\office-ui-fabric-vue\lib\packages\office-ui-fabric-vue\src\...`, but it should be `\office-fabric\packages\office-ui-fabric-vue\lib\...`.

This is the url to the repo: https://github.com/johannes-z/office-fabric/tree/dev
This is the rollup config I'm using: https://github.com/johannes-z/office-fabric/blob/dev/packages/office-ui-fabric-vue/rollup.config.js

What can I change to fix the output path?